# Kotlin Android studio I'm getting an unresolved reference

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to write a little app that asks for a number and then performs a math function. I have a problem with line

```
 editTextNumber2 = editTextNumber * .8
```

I'm getting a message

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public inline operator fun BigDecimal.times(other: BigDecimal): BigDecimal defined in kotlin
public inline operator fun BigInteger.times(other: BigInteger): BigInteger defined in kotlin
```

It gives the suggestion of an editable function, but I get a bit lost. Thank you for your time.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val editTextNumber = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextNumber)
        var editTextNumber2 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextNumber2)
        var editTextNumber3 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextNumber3)
        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            editTextNumber2 = editTextNumber * .8
        }
```

Comment: `editTextNumber` seems to be a view, whereas `.8` is a number, so what would you expect their multiplication to be? What I think you meant to do, was retrieve the current text in the view, attempt to convert it to a number, then multiply. Also I would recommend researching the difference between Android and Android Studio. Android Studio is irrelevant to this question and it's useful in troubleshooting to know the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following code.

```
button.setOnClickListener {
        val data = (editTextNumber.text.toString()).toInt() * 0.8
        editTextNumber2.setText("$data")
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense I was trying to do setText earlier, but I was messing it up. I was trying it in the same line. Thank you so much for the explanation that makes so much  sense now.